3D Model Viewer Not Movable On Desktop – Shopify
I'm trying to add a 3D model to one of my Shopify store's product pages, by uploading it to the media section, but when I do it only works via AR for mobile, and on desktop it just sits there, and when you click on it you cannot manipulate the model in any way.
I have included a link to my page below:
https://magicbrushco.com/products/test-product
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
I have tried reuploading it, but that doesn't do anything. It seems strange to me that this is the normal functionality (if that is the case). I would expect it to work like Google 3D viewer does, which I thought I heard this is based on or something.
In case of any confusion, you can see what I mean if you just scroll slightly on this Google search link, where you can view this element in 3D.
https://www.google.com/search?q=uranium+element&sca_esv=974e9b430d8c4b64&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=ADLYWIK9C4a9sdRiwKLPsMm0pHmQQT2Lpg%3A1715737910156&ei=NhVEZvyFCcmO4-EP27yXiAQ&ved=0ahUKEwj8-KXlxY6GAxVJxzgGHVveBUEQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=uranium+element&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiD3VyYW5pdW0gZWxlbWVudDILEAAYgAQYkQIYigUyCxAAGIAEGJECGIoFMgsQABiABBiRAhiKBTILEAAYgAQYkQIYigUyBRAAGIAEMgsQABiABBiRAhiKBTIFEAAYgAQyBRAAGIAEMgUQABiABDIFEAAYgARI9RJQrQpYyRJwAXgBkAEAmAHJA6AB6QuqAQcyLTEuMS4yuAEDyAEA-AEBmAIFoAK1DMICChAAGLADGNYEGEfCAg0QLhiABBiwAxhDGIoFwgIREAAYgAQYkQIYsQMYgwEYigXCAggQABiABBixA5gDAIgGAZAGCZIHCTEuMC4xLjEuMqAHphY&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

I think you need to check this to know more about Shopify product media 3D https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/product-media/add-media#videos-and-3d-models

Okay, I'm not sure what I was supposed to take from that though?
As you can see, the model is implemented just fine. And it can be viewed in AR on mobile, but on desktop, it does nothing.
